# remember the scrollposition on a new page in react

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, scroll, use-ref

I have a navbar where the user can scroll through different categories and I want the scrollbar's x-position to stay when the user navigates to a new page.

So far i have succeeded to store the scrollbars position in sessionstorage everytime a new category is clicked but how do i use that to set the scrollbars position?

```
export function Navigation({ className }) {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  const [scrollPosX, setScrollPosX] = React.useState(0)

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CATEGORIES_QUERY)

  const handleClickedNavItem = () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("navScrollX", scrollPosX)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
   // set the position of scrollbar on a new page?
},[])

  if (loading) {
    return <Toast show={loading}>Loading..</Toast>
  }

  return (
    <>
      {!loading && (
        <nav
          id="nav-id"
          className={[navStyle, className].join(" ")}
          ref={ref}
          onScroll={() => setScrollPosX(ref.current.scrollLeft)}
        >
          <Link
            key="All"
            className={navLink}
            to="/products/"
            activeClassName={activeLink}
          >
            All Products
          </Link>
          {data.productCategories.nodes.map((category, i) => (
            <Link
              onClick={handleClickedNavItem}
              key={category.name}
              className={navLink}
              to={`/products/${category.slug}`}
              activeClassName={activeLink}
              replace
              onMouseEnter={() => {
                client.query({
                  query: GET_PRODUCTS_FROM_SLUG,
                  variables: { slug: category.slug },
                })
              }}
            >
              {category.name}
            </Link>
          ))}
        </nav>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that things you save in `sessionStorage` always are of type string therefore the conversion.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const storedScrollX = sessionStorage.getItem("navScrollX");
    if (storedScrollX) ref.current?.scrollTo({ left: parseInt(storedScrollX) });
  }, []);
```

I would also suggest adding this to your `onScroll` function as `ref.current` may be undefined:

```
        onScroll={() =>
          setScrollPosX((ref.current && ref.current.scrollLeft) || 0)
        }
```